# Unexpected log off in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: login, 18.04

When I log in to Ubuntu, it logs out of it after some time. It happens only sometimes. It seems to me that when I try to change WiFi settings, this happens. I have tried previous answers, but none work. What could be the problem, or where can I find the reason of problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution? i have the same problem... `18.04.1 LTS`

Comment: Nope, nobody helped. I had to reinstall UBUNTU 16.04 LTS instead.